# ignore case sensitive in regex.replace?

Tags: c#, regex, search, replace, case-sensitive

I have this code to search in a string and replace some text with other text:

```
Regex regexText = new Regex(textToReplace);
retval = regexText.Replace(retval, Newtext);
```

`textToReplace` may be "welcome" or "client" or anything.

I want to ignore case for `textToReplace` so that "welcome" and "Welcome" both match.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may try:

```
Regex regexText = new Regex(textToReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 15):

You simply pass the option `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` like so:

```
Regex regexText = new Regex(textToReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
retval = regexText.Replace(retval, Newtext);
```

Or, if you prefer, you can pass the option directly to the [`Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx):

```
retval = Regex.Replace(retval, textToReplace, Newtext, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

A list of the available options you can set for regexes is available at the [RegexOptions documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, you was first :) so +1 to your post.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Regex.Replace [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx) with [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx). Those options include an IgnoreCase value.